# The [current] tag needs to go away, like, currently

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

So, I just [rejected an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1520398) for the [current](/questions/tagged/current) wiki. I feel this tag is rather... meta. Shall we get rid of it, perhaps?

And yes, this is a call for help. There's only 240 questions (right now) but the more who edit, the faster it goes, right?

[image: Burnman!]

Edit: I think the most creative use of the tag was for an arduino question about electrical current...

Edit: And it's gone. Now how do we keep it from coming back? Because it seems very likely to do so. ;)

Comment: I guess with 240 tags, auto-burnination makes more sense than manual burnination.

Comment: @Manishearth I was dithering between retag or burn. When is it too many, really? =D

Comment: No clue. But <50 can be easily retagged. >50 takes some coordinated effort from more than 2 people.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I hesitating adding that tag because, well, I wasn't sure if we want to ask for burnination. But, that's the second support for it, so... FWOOSH!

Comment: Let Trogdor eat the tag now. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen: manual burnination requests still work with the [burninate-request] tag :)

Comment: @Manishearth A'ight. Noted!

Comment: @Manishearth Not really.  It can be done in about 30-40 minutes.  Frankly, no tags should be burninated from on high.  All questions should be reviewed while performing a tag change such as this.

Comment: @casperOne: Hmm. I guess you mean 'reviewed' there :) 30-40 seems a bit much, though.

Comment: @Manishearth  Consider that the `asp` tag was manually reviewed, and there were *thousands* of questions in that.  The `books` tag is always being hacked at.  Long story short, we aren't in the business anymore of nuking tags, as it creates more noise in the nether regions of the site (it makes it *harder* to find these questions).

Comment: @casperOne: Ah, the "fix everything else while you're at it" thing. Gotcha.

Comment: @Manishearth I've already cleared 40.  It's not hard at all.  I'l have the rest done in a bit.

Comment: @casperOne I'm helping, I'm helping! ;)

Comment: @casperOne: you have inline tag editing _glares_

Comment: Yeah. Having that would make it sooooooo much easier.

Comment: @Manishearth Yeah, that helps.  Also, you work from the *last* page forward, that helps tremendously as well.  If you work from forward back, you get lost pretty quickly in the edits.  141 left.

Comment: @casperOne I tried that. But since you have inline tag editing, I couldn't keep up with you, so I went from the front instead. And now Manishearth is doing that, so I'm squished in the middle. ;)

Comment: What was the [tag:current] tag being used for?

Comment: @JamesWebster Everything. "current user" mistagging, "electrical current" mistagging, "current location" mistagging, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a little longer than 30-40 minutes, but it's finally gone.

Seems likely it'll return due to interesting tag-attempts such as "current user" or "current time". But for now... peace.

Comment: Arrrrgh! There were a bunch of really really bad questions in that tag. The idea was to go through and fix them all up, and, while doing so, remove the tag. Just willy-nilly deleting the tag was a bad idea: it served as a signpost to questions which needed tidying.

Comment: @TRiG I was attempting to fix the questions I thought really bad, in the portion I did. But I may not have done enough. Since I have the ones I did in my revision-tab in my summary, I can go through all the ones I've done and review them again.

Comment: It's just that I was in the middle of editing http://stackoverflow.com/q/9946533/209139 when your edit came through, and when I went to view yours I'd lost mine. Redone it now. (Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9947938/209139, which as a good answer to a bad X/Y question.) Leaving the rest and going on lunch.

Comment: @TRiG I do apologise, not my intention to mess things up. One gets... caught up in tag-removals. =)

Comment: And I, perhaps, get caught up in rewriting posts. I'm a proofreader by nature. Misplaced commas bug me exceedingly.